# know the point of ending the method chaining in php oop

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

Can you help me?

please let me know the point of ending the chain?

for example:

```
class A {
     // some static function
}
A::string()->hash() // return 'abcd'
A::string()->hash()->replace('a','z') // return 'zbcd'
A::string()->hash()->replace('a','z')->sub(0,2) // return 'zb'
```

How can I write function?

Comment: May be it's just me, but I don't get the question. Please elaborate.

Comment: add some more description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to perform different operations on an input string by chaining as many methods as you want. Then you can have a method that when called returns the final content of the string after manipulation. You might want to store the result of this operation in a variable without necessarily having to echo it to the browser.
Here is a way you can achieve this

```
<?php

class A {

    /**
    *@var string The string to manipulate
    */
    private static $string;

    /**
    *This method replaces parts of a string with another string value.
    *@param string $string The string whose content is to be searched and replaced
    *@param string $search The string to search for in the $string
    *@param string $replace The string to replace with the $search string
    *@param \Object This static class
    */
    public static  function replace($string = null, $search, $replace)
    {
        //check if input string is provided and set the value of the string property
        if($string !== null) self::$string = $string;

        //evaluate and set the value of the string property
        self::$string = str_replace($search, $replace, self::$string);

        //return this static class
        return new static;
    }

    /**
    *This method returns part of the string.
    *@param string $string The string whose part is to be returned
    *@param int $start Where to start truncating from
    *@param int $count The number of characters to return from the starting point
    *@param \Object This static class
    */
    public static  function sub($string = null, $start, $count)
    {
        //check if input string is provided and set the value of the string property
        if($string !== null) self::$string = $string;

        //evaluate and set the value of the string property
        self::$string = substr(self::$string, $start, $count );

        //return this static class
        return new static;
    }

    /**
    *This method returns the final string after manipulation.
    *@param null
    *@return string The value of $string property
    */
    public static function get()
    {
       //return the contents of the string property 
       return self::$string;
    }

}

//here are the options you can have
$string = A::replace($string, $search, $replace)->sub($start, $count)->get(); //replace, get substring and return string
$string = A::replace($string, $search, $replace)->get(); //replace and return string
$string = A::sub($string, $start, $count)->replace($search, $replace)->get(); //get substring, replace and return string
$string = A::sub($string, $start, $count)->get(); //get substring and return string
?>
```

With this class, you don't have to be forced to `echo` in order to get the contents of the final string, just store it in a variable and use as you wish.
This class enables you to chain methods and then call the last `get()` to terminate the chain and return the final string value. You can call the method in any order `A::replace()->sub()->get()` or `A::sub()->replace()->get()` calling the `get()` as the last  to terminate the chain. You only need to pass the `$string` value once with the first method you call and it's value would be preserved for other chained methods. So for example, you would do this `A::replace($string, $search, $replace)->sub($start, $count)->get()` or `A::sub($string, $start, $count)->replace($search, $replace)->get()`

Answer (score 1):

The static method `string` is a factory method. It is used to create a new instance of the class. The rest of the methods must return the object itself to maintain the chainability. Also, by implementing the `__toString` method, the object can be printed or concatenated to a string.

```
class A {
    protected $string;

    public function __construct($string = null)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
    }
    public static function string($string = 'abcd')
    {
        return new self($string);
    }
    public function hash()
    {
        return $this;
    }
    public function replace($search, $replace)
    {
        $this->string = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->string);
        return $this;
    }
    public function sub($start, $count)
    {
        $this->string = substr($this->string, $start, $count);
        return $this;
    }
    public function toString()
    {
        return $this->string;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->toString();
    }
}

echo A::string()->hash(); // prints 'abcd'
echo A::string()->hash()->replace('a','z'); // prints 'zbcd'
echo A::string()->hash()->replace('a','z')->sub(0,2); // prints 'zb'
```